# How to isolate two c++ classes with the same name?

Tags: c++, g++, elf

I have a project with a bunch of C++ test files. Each test file declares a class like this:

```
// test1.cpp
...
class Foo { void bar() {...} };
...
```

and

```
// test2.cpp
...
class Foo { void bar() {...} };
...
```

and so on.

Everything was fine until the test suite became quite big and the contents of `Foo` class became different in some test modules. Things go wrong when it comes to linkage. The methods of the class in each ELF file are declared as public weak ("W" in `nm` notation) symbols and it results in calling wrong instances of the method, e.g. `tests1.cpp` calls `Foo::bar()` from `tests2.cpp`.

How does one isolate one instance of `class Foo` from another?

Declaring the class with `__attributes__ ((visibility ("hidden")))` doesn't help, the symbols remain public.

Also for sure I can use namespaces for this but I'd prefer to avoid this option.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you prefer to avoid namespaces? It's pretty much the reason they were invented!

Comment: You could use anonymous namespaces, Wrapping the `Foo` declaration in a `namespace { class Foo { ... }; }` should work just the same and make the `Foo` internal to the compilation unit.

Comment: @Steve I would like to fix things once (e.g. in a makefile) rather than each time invent a new name for a namespace.

Comment: @krokoziabla: You don't need to invent a name - see my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The suspicion you have with namespaces insofar that you don't want to attribute arbitrary names to them is unfounded.

This is a perfect job for *anonymous namespaces*. Write

```
namespace /*no name here makes it anonymous*/{
    class Foo { void bar() {...} };
}
```

and so on. Doing this internalises `Foo` to that particular translation unit.

Comment: Well, using anonymous namespaces solve the problem. I was just afraid that I couldn't put a GTest's test into one. But it seems I can... So I should thank you. But... Is there a way to fix it not in the sources but on the compiler's side?

Comment: @krokoziabla: My reservations in doing that is that then your source files move away from being directly compilable. I'd suffer the extra text if I were you.

Comment: @krokoziabla — you might be able to figure out a way to use a hammer to drive in a screw, but you’ll be much better off using a screwdriver.